# how does scala interpreter execute source file directly without creating class file

Tags: scala

I have this scala code

```
object S extends App{
    println("This is trait program")
}
```

When I execute `scala S.scala` it executes fine.
Now I want to know how can it execute code without compile and creating of class file.

Answer (score 4):

Scala is a compiled language, and it needs to compile the code and the .class file is needed for execution.

Maybe you are thinking in using the REPL, where you can interactively code: https://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html#run-it-interactively

But, under the hood, the REPL is compiling your code, and executing the compiled .class

Comment: I executed my code using cmd in windows 8 by using scala S.scala command and it is working fine that's why i am wondering.

Comment: @irfankhan it's still compiled, however the class files are unavailable to users in that case.

Comment: @HongxuChen OK, thanks. but why class files are hide/unavailable? is there any specific reason?

Comment: how would it be useful to have such compiled files?

Comment: @irfankhan just for temporary use. FYI, during compilation of almost all compilation languages, there are also EXTRA temporary *representations*; e.g., compilation of a `main.c` file a corresponding object file *main.o* is required.

Answer (score 1):

The command `scala` that you are launching is used to launch Scala REPL, and if you provide a file as an argument, it'll execute it will execute the content of the files as if it was bulk pasted in a REPL.

It's true that Scala is a compiled language, but it does not mean that a `.class` file is necessary. All that the Scala compiler needs to do is generate relevant JVM byte code and call JVM with that byte code. This does not mean that it explicitly has to create a `.class` file in directory from where you called it. It can do it all using memory and temporary storage and just call JVM with generated byte code.

If you are looking to explicitly generate class files with Scala that you can later execute by calling `java` manually, you should use Scala compiler CLI (command: `scalac`).

Please note that Scala compiler has interfaces to check and potentially compile Scala code on the fly, which is very useful for IDEs (checkout IntelliJ and Ensime).

Answer (score 1):

Just call `main()` on the object (which inherits this method from App):

```
S.main(Array())
```

`main()` expects an `Array[String]`, so you can just provide an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Scala is a compiled language in terms of source code to java bytecode transition, however some tricks may be taken to make it *resemble* an interpreted language. A naive implementation is that when run `scala myscript.scala`, it follows these steps:

1. `scalac Myscript.scala`. It generates `S.class` (which is the entry class that contains `main` method) and potentially other class files.
2. `scala -cp . S`. This runs/interprets from the main entry of the class
   file. `-cp .` specifies the classpath; and `S` is the entry class without file extension `.class`. Note that *run*/*interprets* means interpreting (java) bytecode (rather than Scala/Java source code), which is done by JVM runtime.
3. Remove all the temporarily generated class files. This procedure is optional as long as the users are not aware of the temporary files (i.e., *transparent* to users).

That is to say, `scala` acts as a *driver* that may handle 0) initialization 1) compilation(`scalac`) 2) execute/run (`scala`) 3) cleanup.
The actual procedures may be different (e.g., due to performance concerns some files are only in memory/cached, or not generated, or not deleted, by using lower-level APIs of `scala` driver, etc.) but the general idea should be similar.
On Linux machines, you might find some evidences in `/tmp` folder. For me,

```
$ tree /tmp
/tmp
├── hsperfdata_hongxu
│   └── 64143
└── scala-develhongxu
    ├── output-redirects
    │   ├── scala-compile-server-err.log
    │   └── scala-compile-server-out.log
    └── scalac-compile-server-port
        └── 34751

4 directories, 4 files
```

It is also noteworthy that this way of running Scstepsala is not full-fledged. For example, `package` declarations are not supported.

```
# MyScript.scala
package hw
object S extends App {
  println("Hello, world!")
}
```

And it emit error:

```
$ scala Myscript.scala
.../Myscript.scala:1: error: illegal start of definition
package hw
^
one error found
```

Others have also mentioned the REPL (read–eval–print loop), which is quite similar. Essentially, almost every language *can* have an (interactive) interpreter. Here is a text from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop#Overview):

> REPLs can be created to support any language. REPL support for compiled languages is usually achieved by implementing an interpreter on top of a virtual machine which provides an interface to the compiler. Examples of REPLs for compiled languages include CINT (and its successor Cling), Ch, and BeanShell

However interpreted languages (Python, Ruby, etc.) are typically superior due to their dynamic nature and runtime VMs/interpreters.

Additionally, the gap between `compiled` and `interpreted` is not that big. And you can see Scala actually has some *interpreted* features (at least it *appears*) since it makes you feel that you can execute like a script language.